# How can jenkins build a IntelliJ project (not maven/gradle)?

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea

I prefer the IntelliJ project format for a Kotlin/JVM project. I.e. the dependencies and other project information is kept in files within the `.idea` directory:

[image: screenshot of project structure]

Using IntelliJ IDEA I run tests and create an uber-JAR artifact for deployment.

Questions:

- How can I build and test a IntelliJ Kotlin/JVM project on Jenkins? Is there a plug-in available that can handle the IntelliJ project format?
- Or do I have to duplicate the project's information in a gradle file?

Comment: How about using the Kotlin CLI https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html

Comment: That would have the same problems as creating a gradle file, mainly extracting/duplicating the dependency information from the IntelliJ project directory.